# Zip File Extract not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: zip, unzip

I have recently upgraded my system OS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I have some zip files generated from another machine having OS Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

When I try to extract the file in my OS, I get the error:

```
An Error occurred while loading the archive
```

I tried `unzip` and it also does not extract the files.

Does anyone face the same issue? Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Run  `file filename.zip` to see if the zip signature is still present. Then `unzip -t filename.zip` to see what unzip thinks about the file. Update the question with the details.

Answer (score 1):

try using XArchiver - it's more flexible in understanding of the compression used:

```
sudo apt install xarchiver
```

then locate your files with Nautilus or whatever commander you are using, right click on them and open with xarchiver or "extract here".

good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I installed xarchiver. Right click on the file and extracted with xarchiver. I got this message "Can't open file "/home/zips/demo1.zip:: Archive Format is not recognized!"

Comment: can you share one of these zip files somewhere ?